# How do I correctly format YAML to upload objects into my DB using frozen_record gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I'm trying to load some questions into my Question model using [Frozen Record](https://github.com/byroot/frozen_record) and a YAML file. For some reason the formatting is off, and I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. The intention is that FrozenRecord will upload my /config/initializers/questions.yml file and create three new Question records, with the parameters below:

The Question Model:

```
class Question < FrozenRecord::Base
 include ActiveModel::Validations
 validates :next_question_id_yes, :question_text, :answer_type, presence: true
 self.base_path = 'config/initializers/'
end
```

The Questions.yml file:

```
questions:
- id: 1
    question_text: Why does this company need to buy your products or services?
    answer_type: Text Field
    next_question_id_yes: 2
    next_question_id_no: ~
- id: 2
    question_text: When do they need to have completed the project?
    answer_type: Datetime
    next_question_id_yes: 3
    next_question_id_no: ~
- id: 3
    question_text: What happens if they miss this deadline?
    answer_type: Text Field
    next_question_id_yes: 4
    next_question_id_no: ~
```

I get the following error:

```
Psych::SyntaxError: (config/initializers/questions.yml): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 18
```

So presumably something is wrong on line 3, but I have no idea what it might be. I've tried adding "" around the string, but that didn't help. I can't seem to find anything that tells me how to format an entire object as YAML and upload to the DB (only results about using to_yaml methods to pull objects out as YAML).

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is proper format of the `YAML` file:

```
- id: 1
  question_text: Why does this company need to buy your products or services?
  answer_type: Text Field
  next_question_id_yes: 2
  next_question_id_no: ~
- id: 2
  question_text: When do they need to have completed the project?
  answer_type: Datetime
  next_question_id_yes: 3
  next_question_id_no: ~
- id: 3
  question_text: What happens if they miss this deadline?
  answer_type: Text Field
  next_question_id_yes: 4
  next_question_id_no: ~
```

Comment: Thanks - I used your formatting but got the following error:  `NoMethodError: undefined method 'keys' for #<Array:0x007f9755218650> ` when running the Rails Console with the  `Question.find(1) ` command.

Comment: Actually - don't worry. I'd kept the `questions:` aspect of the YAML file, as soon as I adopted your code exactly it worked as expected. Thanks a lot.